# how to make static variable initialize to global variable

Tags: php

the problem is want to change the value of global variable each time sub is called ,how can i possibly do it

```
         function sub()
             {
           static $x=global $present;
            static $y=global $max;
            static $z=global $min;
        if($x==$z)
        {
     $x=$y;
             }
            $x--;

          return $x;
               }

            sub();
             sub();
              sub();
```

i have tried this too

```
          function sub()
             {
            global $present;
            global $max;
            global $min;
        if($present==$min)
        {
     $present=$max;
             }
            $present--;

          return $present;
               }

              sub();//it works only once
              sub();
              sub();
```

please provide me the solution so that i can change the value of global variable each time function is called.......thank you

the main function of sub is retrieving value frm data base but ,src remains same no matter how many times i call change function please help me out

```
         function sub()
              {
global $present;
global $max;
global $min;
       if($present==$min)
        {
$present=$max;
          }
          else
           --$present;
         return $present;   
              }


               <script>
            function change()
                  {

                    alert("hello"); 
                var x=document.getElementById("show");
       x.src='<?php



         if($con==true)
            {

      $cmd="select * from showcase where item_no=".sub();
           if($res=$con->query($cmd))
              {
      if($res->num_rows>0)
            {
          while($rw=$res->fetch_array())
           {

           echo "$rw[1]";
                }
                 }
     else
      {
     echo "no record found";
        }
         }
        else
  {
       echo "query problem";
      }}

           ?>'; 
             alert(x.src);
                     }
                  </script>
```

Comment: Have you ever heard about [indentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation) ?

Comment: didnt get you sorry??

Comment: @Maerlyn i have put the actual use...now in addition to my qustn pls see now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
<?php

$x = 5;

function sub() {
    global $x;

    --$x;
}

sub(); var_dump($x);
sub(); var_dump($x);
sub(); var_dump($x);
sub(); var_dump($x);
```

Output is 4, 3, 2, 1. See for yourself: http://3v4l.org/Tic1v

Comment: You're horribly mixing client- and server-side code. That cannot be simply fixed.